# Automatizar navegação em sites para atividades de teste de software

Tags: java, c#, web-crawler, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Estou em um projeto de desenvolvimento de sistemas web, acessados pelo navegador. Estamos constantemente realizando modificações no funcionamento dos processos e a cada período específico realizamos um teste nas funcionalidades do sistema (cadastros, validações, botões, dimensões e etc). Muitas destas tarefas são repetitivas, longas e feitas manualmente, então gostaria de desenvolver (em Java ou C#) uma aplicação para realizar tais testes de forma automatizada. Conforme fosse necessário eu apenas incrementaria mais testes na aplicação.

O que eu preciso: navegar pelo site, tirar printscreen de determinadas páginas, simular cliques, simular movimentos do mouse, preencher campos, capturar elementos da página, rolar a página. E principalmente simular diferentes navegadores, inclusive móveis (acessos via smartphone). Ou seja, tudo o que um cliente faria naturalmente em meu sistema.

Como posso realizar isso com uma destas linguagens? Existe uma biblioteca para isso?

Grato.

Comment: Veja se te atende: http://www.seleniumhq.org

Comment: O Selenium utiliza o navegador do sistema? Ele possui aquele server..

Comment: Utiliza o navegador do sistema e também tem a opção de não utilizar

Comment: Estou em busca de navegador headless. Não tenho necessidade de um navegador visível.

Comment: Você pode configurar o selenium para usar o PhantomJS, que é headless.